# How to remove empty space in a table cell ?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablecell

In the code below I have set `max-width` for table cells, so all of them have equal width irrespective of content they carry and `vertical-align` is set to top. But as you see first cell is quite lengthy as compared to second and third so there is huge space left between 2nd-5th and 3rd-6th table cells. Is there any way to remove that space ? I mean I want 5th and 6th cells to follow the above cells immediately and not to wait for 1st cell to end.

```css
table tr td {
  vertical-align:top;
  max-width:90px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is first cell. this will be quite lengthy</td>
    <td>this is second cell</td>
    <td>this is third cell</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>this is fouth cell</td>
    <td>this is fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: @dippas yes ,is there any css solution?

Comment: You could use floating `<div>` elements instead of table cells to get that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you want is tables are set up to function like that so it keeps everything aligned and organized.  As mentioned you might want to look more into the masonry layout if you want separate squares to stack together like different sized bricks, a table won't work in that instance because it's not built to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't care if cells 5 and 6 align with cell 4, as long as they align with each other and get rid of that empty space. In many cases it's better to use divs than tables for this sort of thing, but here's a solution that retains tables.

You'll have to create a second table if you want to break row alignment, so the first table will have cells 1 and 4 and the second will have cells 2, 3, 5, and 6. For your style, use `display:inline-block` to get the tables to sit next to each other, and enclose them in `<div>`s (never use nested tables) with `display:inline; vertical align:top;` if you want the two tables to align at the top. The end result is something like this:

```
<head>

<style>
table tr td {
  vertical-align:top;
  max-width:90px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: black;
}
.talign{
display:inline-block;
}
.dalign{
display:inline;
vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='dalign'>
<table class='talign'>
  <tr>
    <td>this is first cell. this will be quite lengthy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is fouth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class='dalign'>
<table class='talign'>
  <tr>
    <td>this is second cell</td>
    <td>this is third cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```